# Keep pagination beetween tabs in Shiny datatables

Tags: r, pagination, shiny, dt

I have three datatables rendered in a tabsetpanel, and what I need to do is to keep the current page of one datatable into the others. For example, if i'm in the page 1 in the datatable1 and I go to page 2, I want the datatable2 and 3 to be in the page 2.

This is the code that I have, any ideas?

```
shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        # hides the default search functionality
        tags$style(
          HTML(".dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(10, 
               ""
        ), 
        column(2,              
               uiOutput("pageFilter")
               #numericInput("page", "Page", 1, min = 1)
        ),
        column(12,
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel('pressure',
                          DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1")),
                 tabPanel('mtcars',
                          DT::dataTableOutput("mytable2")),
                 tabPanel('iris',
                          DT::dataTableOutput("mytable3"))
               )
        )
      )
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part is to use the `stateSave` parameter, see below:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
app <- shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      # hides the default search functionality
      tags$style(
        HTML(".dataTables_filter, .dataTables_info { display: none; }")
      )
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(10, 
             ""
      ), 
      column(2,              
             # adding new page filter
             uiOutput("pageFilter")
      ),
      column(12,
             tabsetPanel(id = "tab",
                tabPanel('pressure',
                  dataTableOutput('table1')
                ),
                tabPanel('mtcars',
                  dataTableOutput('table2')
                )
             )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

    global <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
      global$val <- input$table1_state$start / input$table1_state$length + 1
     })

    observe({
      global$val <- input$table2_state$start / input$table2_state$length + 1
    })

    output$pageFilter <- renderUI({
      numericInput("page", "Page", global$val, min = 1)
    })

    output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
      iris
    }, options = list(pageLength = 5, stateSave = TRUE))

    output$table2 = DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    }, options = list(pageLength = 5, stateSave = TRUE))

    # using new page filter
    observeEvent({input$page; input$tab}, {
      dataTableProxy("table1") %>% selectPage(global$val)
      dataTableProxy("table2") %>% selectPage(global$val)
    })

  }
)

runApp(app, launch.browser =  TRUE)
```